# Spark 2.0.0 twitter streaming driver is no longer available

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, twitter-streaming-api

During migration from spark 1.6.2 to spark 2.0.0 appeared that package org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter has been removed and twitter streaming is no longer available as well as dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Can anyone suggest how to procced twitter stream in new spark?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Twitter (and some other) driver support has been removed in Spark 2.0.

You can see it in the removal section of the [Release Notes](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-0-0.html):

> ### Removals
>
> #### The following features have been removed in Spark 2.0:
>
> - Less frequently used streaming connectors, including Twitter, Akka,
>     MQTT, ZeroMQ

They have been extracted as a separate package under the [Bahir Project](http://bahir.apache.org/). The twitter extension, [streaming-twitter](https://github.com/apache/bahir/tree/master/streaming-twitter), can be found via:

sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "2.0.0"
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.bahir</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-preview</version>
</dependency>
```

More on that (thanks to @IvanShulak) in the [Mailing List](https://www.mail-archive.com/user%40spark.apache.org/msg54946.html)

### Edit:

For Spark 2.0.1, use:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "2.0.1"
```

Comment: thanks Yuval for replay. Is it dependency available in global maven repository? Cause I can't find it in [maven repo](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.spark-project%22) and also getting error in my pom file: Missing artifact org.spark-project:dstream-twitter_2.10:jar:0.1.0

Comment: @IvanShulak I guess it should be available soon. There's an open [bug about](https://github.com/spark-packages/dstream-twitter/issues/1) it

Comment: thanks for help. I've updated your answer and added correct mvn dependency following your link in previous comment.

Comment: @IvanShulak Thanks for the update Ivan. Modified the original answer to suit the findings.

Comment: You should now be able to use:  "org.apache.bahir" % "spark-streaming-twitter_2.11" % "2.0.1"