# How to read messages in MQs using spark streaming,i.e ZeroMQ，RabbitMQ?

Tags: apache-spark, zeromq

As the spark docs says,it support kafka as data streaming source.but I use ZeroMQ,And there is not a ZeroMQUtils.so how can I use it? and generally,how about other MQs. I am totally new to spark and spark streaming, so I am sorry if the question is stupid.Could anyone give me a solution.Thanks
BTW,I use python.

Update, I finally did it in java with a Custom Receiver. Below is my solution

```java
public class ZeroMQReceiver extends Receiver<T> {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public ZeroMQReceiver() {

        super(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // Start the thread that receives data over a connection
        new Thread(this::receive).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        // There is nothing much to do as the thread calling receive()
        // is designed to stop by itself if isStopped() returns false
    }

    /** Create a socket connection and receive data until receiver is stopped */
    private void receive() {
        String message = null;

        try {

            ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1); 
            ZMQ.Socket subscriber = context.socket(ZMQ.SUB);     
            subscriber.connect("tcp://ip:port");    
            subscriber.subscribe("".getBytes());  

            // Until stopped or connection broken continue reading
            while (!isStopped() && (message = subscriber.recvStr()) != null) {
                List<T> results = mapper.readValue(message,
                        new TypeReference<List<T>>(){} );
                for (T item : results) {
                    store(item);
                }
            }
            // Restart in an attempt to connect again when server is active again
            restart("Trying to connect again");
        } catch(Throwable t) {
            // restart if there is any other error
            restart("Error receiving data", t);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Spark 2.0.0 twitter streaming driver is no longer available](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38714256/10465355) - https://bahir.apache.org/

Comment: Structured Streaming or DStreams?

Comment: @Bernhard Stadler，both are ok, as I said, I'm totally new, any solutions?

Comment: @youngjack What about the answer I posted (Structured Streaming usually is better from a developer POV)? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about Structured Streaming.

I am not familiar with ZeroMQ, but an important point in Spark Structured Streaming sources is replayability (in order to ensure fault tolerance), which, if I understand correctly, ZeroMQ doesn't deliver out-of-the-box.

A practical approach would be buffering the data either in Kafka and using the KafkaSource or as files in a (local FS/NFS, HDFS, S3) directory and using the FileSource for reading. Cf. [Spark Docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#creating-streaming-dataframes-and-streaming-datasets). If you use the FileSource, make sure not to append anything to an existing file in the FileSource's input directory, but move them into the directory atomically.

Comment: I finally did it in java with a Custom Receiver, but still thanks, I'll check Structured Streaming.

Comment: @youngjack - Could you post the solution? I need similar connector.