# Problem with transformation JavaRDD<Status> to JavaRDD<String>

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, spark-streaming, objectmapper

I'm trying to save tweets from  twitter to MongoDb database.

I have got `RDD<Status>` and i'm trying to convert this one to JSON format with help ObjectMapper.But there is some problem with this transformation(

```java
public class Main {


    //set system credentials for access to twitter
    private static void setTwitterOAuth() {
        System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", TwitterCredentials.consumerKey);
        System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", TwitterCredentials.consumerSecret);
        System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", TwitterCredentials.accessToken);
        System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", TwitterCredentials.accessTokenSecret);
    }


    public static void main(String [] args) {

        setTwitterOAuth();

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]")
                                        .setAppName("SparkTwitter");
        JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkContext, new Duration(1000));
        JavaReceiverInputDStream<Status> twitterStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(jssc);

        //Stream that contains just tweets in english
        JavaDStream<Status> enTweetsDStream=twitterStream.filter((status) -> "en".equalsIgnoreCase(status.getLang()));
        enTweetsDStream.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK());


        enTweetsDStream.print();
        jssc.start();
        jssc.awaitTermination();
    }

    static void saveRawTweetsToMondoDb(JavaRDD<Status> rdd,JavaSparkContext sparkContext) {
     try {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext);
            JavaRDD<String> tweet =  rdd.map(status -> objectMapper.writeValueAsString(status));

            DataFrame dataFrame = sqlContext.read().json(tweet);

            Map<String, String> writeOverrides = new HashMap<>();
            writeOverrides.put("uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/forensicdb.LiveRawTweets");
            WriteConfig writeConfig = WriteConfig.create(sparkContext).withJavaOptions(writeOverrides);
            MongoSpark.write(dataFrame).option("collection", "LiveRawTweets").mode("append").save();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error saving to database");
        }
    }

JavaRDD<String> tweet =  rdd.map(status -> objectMapper.writeValueAsString(status));
```

here is a problem.Incompatible types required `JavaRDD<String>` but map was inferred to `javaRDD<R>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java type inference isn't always super smart unfortunately, so what I do in these cases is extracting all the bits of my lambda as variables until I find one that Java can't give an accurate type for. I then give the expression the type I think it should have and see why Java is complaining about it. Sometimes it will just be a limitation in the compiler and you'll have to explicitly "cast" the expression as the desired type, other times you'll find an issue with your code. In your case, the code ooks fine to me so there must be something else.

I have a comment however: here you are paying the cost of JSON serialization once (from `Status` to JSON string) and then deserialization (from JSON string to `Row`). Plus, you're not providing any schema to your `Dataset` so it will have to make two passes of the data (or a sample of it depending on your config) to infer the schema. All that can be quite expensive if the data is large. I would advise you to write a conversion from `Status` to `Row` directly if performance is a concern and if `Status` is relatively simple.

Another "by the way": you are implicitly serializing your `ObjectMapper`, chances are you don't want to do that. It seems like the class does support Java serialization, but with [special logic](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.java#L375). Since the default config for Spark is to use Kryo (which has much better performance than Java serialization), I doubt it will do the right thing when using the default `FieldSerializer`. You have three options:

- make the object mapper static to avoid serializing it
- configure your Kryo registrator to serialize/deserialize objects of type `ObjectMapper` with Java serialization. That would work but not worth the effort.
- use Java serialization everywhere instead of Kryo. Bad idea! It's slow and uses a lot of space (memory and disk depending on where the serialized objects will be written).

Comment: "I would advise you to write a conversion from Status to Row directly if performance is a concern and if Status is relatively simple."Could you please provide example)? It wasn't clear for me)Thanks)

Comment: @AlexanderRomanov with the map function (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html), you could convert a `Status` into a `Row`. Actually re-reading your code, you might be using an old version of Spark that didn't have this feature, because the `DataFrame` class was removed.

Comment: Otherwise, did you try extracting the lambda out to see what the compiler says?

Comment: What do you mean extract the lambda?I'm using 1.6.2 spark version.

Comment: You may want to upgrade your Spark distribution if you can, 1.6 is pretty old now. I mean extracting the lambda function in a variable instead of having it directly in the `map` statement

Comment: I'm using this spark version because according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714256/spark-2-0-0-twitter-streaming-driver-is-no-longer-available i can't read data from twitter in older version.My apologize, i'm again cant understand you(xtracting the lambda function in a variable instead of having it directly in the map statement) could you please provide an example?

Comment: `status -> objectMapper.writeValueAsString(status)` this is a lambda function, I'm just suggesting to store it in a variable with the type you expect it to be and see if the compiler complains about it or not.

Comment: The StackOverflow post you linked also has a solution to fix the issue. You just have to add a custom dependency to your project instead of having the Twitter classes being distributed in the main Spark distribution. This is because Spark 2.0 has moved away from distributing a single jar to instead distributing all of its dependencies, and its own modules, in separate jars so that people can better handle classpath conflicts and also pick what they need or not.

Comment: I used to use this dependency from bahir.But he didn't work.

Comment: According to this guide https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial  objectMapper.writeValueAsString generates a JSON from a Java object and returns the generated JSON as a string or as a byte array:

Comment: Yeah I know, but just try extracting it out as I explained and see what happens. I haven't tried to compile your code but visually it looks ok.

Comment: Everything ok)I just run code and check how writeValueAsString() and i get result like this {"rateLimitStatus":null,"accessLevel":0,"createdAt":1566068331000,"id":11628":1004407330107248640,"favoriteCount":0,"inReplyToScreenName":"Piklefn","geoLocation":null,"place":null,"retweetCount":0,"lang":"en","retweetedStatus":null,"userMentionEntities":[{"start":0,"end":8,"name":"Pikle Pinned","screenName":"Piklefn","id":1004407330107248640,"text":"Piklefn"}],"hashtagEntities":[],"mediaEntities":[],"extendedMediaEntities":...

Comment: Your question made it look like you had a compile error, but now your code is  running? What's wrong with the result you had? Seems ok to me

Comment: No, everything is ok with ObjectMapper() he is working).As you recomended i  extracted out ObjectMapper() and provided result of his execution in previous comment. String status = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(rdd.first())

Comment: But error with this line:JavaRDD<String> tweet =  rdd.map(status -> objectMapper.writeValueAsString(status)) stayed.As you recommended i will try conversion from Status to Row directly tomorrow. But i really can't understand why this code doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think this is what I meant. I suggested to write that: `Function<Status, String> toJsonString = status -> objectMapper.writeValueAsString(status); JavaRDD<String> tweet = rdd.map(toJsonString);` and see what the compiler tells you

Comment: Function<Status, String> toJsonString = status -> objectMapper.writeValueAsString(status);JavaRDD<String> tweet = (JavaRDD<String>) rdd.map(toJsonString); Everythyng is ok)Compiler allows this  expression thanks)

Comment: Cool, I don't understand what the problem was then, probably just the compiler being a bit stupid!

Comment: Thank you again, that was at first time in my career when problem in compiler not in me)

Comment: Hi, again)Could you please help me again?Question related to previous but a little different)Could you please explain me more detail what does it mean:" Plus, you're not providing any schema to your Dataset so it will have to make two passes of the data (or a sample of it depending on your config) to infer the schema. All that can be quite expensive if the data is large. I would advise you to write a conversion from Status to Row directly if performance is a concern and if Status is relatively simple."It wasn't clear for me)However i'm trying to save Status to mongodb without defining scheme.

Comment: Does it poosible to smth like that in Java? MongoSpark.save(rawTweetsDF.coalesce(1).write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.json").option("forensicdb",
"LiveRawTweets").mode("append"), writeConfig)

Comment: Please take a look in my post if you are interested)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57649731/cant-save-dataframe-to-mongodb?noredirect=1#comment101750365_57649731

Comment: Hello, just saw the comments. I'll have a loot at the question

Comment: Sure, here or in this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57649731/cant-save-dataframe-to-mongodb?noredirect=1#comment101750365_57649731?